# Sort a text aggregate created with array_agg in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql. The following table "animals" will do to explain my problem:

```
name
------
tiger
cat
dog
```

Now I am using the following query:

```
SELECT
    array_to_string(array_agg("name"), ', ')
FROM
    animals;
```

The result is: "tiger, cat, dog". But I would like to sort the aggregate, before it is converted into a string. So this is the result I am hoping for:

```
"cat, dog, tiger".
```

So how can I sort an string array in postgresql 8.4 before converting it to a string. ORDER BY on the row "name" does not work and the built-in sort function processes only integer values.

Anyone a good idea, how to solve this in pure SQL?

Thanx a lot
Richard

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will be available in PostgreSQL 9.0:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/release-9-0.html, Section E.1.3.6.1. Aggregates

In the meantime, you could do something like this which may solve the problem (albeit clunky):

```
SELECT array_agg(animal_name)
FROM (
    SELECT "name" AS animal_name
    FROM animals
    ORDER BY "name"
) AS sorted_animals;
```

Comment: This will do! And very happy to know that it will be implemented in 9.0.

Answer (score 66):

Use an [`ORDER BY` clause in an aggregate expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT
    array_to_string(array_agg(name ORDER BY name), ', ')
FROM
    animals;
```

Also, for your specific purpose, you can use [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE) to simplify your query:

```
SELECT
    string_agg(name, ', ' ORDER BY name)
FROM
    animals;
```

Answer (score 4):

Although Matthew Wood's answer is better for your case, here is a way to sort arrays in PostgreSQL 8.4 and up:

```
SELECT array(
    SELECT unnest(array[3,2,1]) AS x ORDER BY x
);
```

Knowing the `array` and `unnest` functions can be handy, since it also lets you do things like ["map"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) over an array:

```
SELECT array(
    SELECT x*x FROM (SELECT unnest(array[1,2,3]) AS x) as subquery
);
```

Again, this can be yours for the price of PostgreSQL 8.4 .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `generate_series()` on the array, and then do a `SELECT...ORDER BY` on that result (or just nest it inside of the `SELECT`) before you convert it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Still, for version 8.4, using the solution suggested by Matthew Wood, if you need to do a grouping in the outer query, the inner query should be sorted, too, for the sorting to be consistent.

```
SELECT family, array_agg(animal_name)
FROM (
    SELECT family, "name" AS animal_name
    FROM animals
    ORDER BY family, "name"
) AS sorted_animals
group by family;
```

Answer (score 0):

To update on this question, Snowflake has implemented array sorting:

```
SELECT
    array_sort(array_agg("name")
FROM
    animals;
```

Can also use `array_sort_by` to sort an object