# multilingual select sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, multilingual

I'm trying to select rows in specific language if not I want to get default one. Translation for `lang_id = 1` always exists.

I have such a table:

```
car_id | name | lang_id
```

and here is my select

```
select  c1.*,
        COALESCE(c2.name, c1.name) as name
        from cars c1
        left join cars c2 on c1.car_id= c2.car_id and c2.lang_id=2
        where c1.lang_id = 1 limit 10;
```

but I want to also apply filter on name to be able to search by name. I know I can apply few more statements in where by `c2.name ilike` and so on... but I have feeling it is not right way.

Also will be better to avoid joins...

I think here about one approach: on new insert add records for all languages in default language name to avoid joins later. But that will increase db used space.

What will be best solutions in this case?

Comment: Translations between languages are not a black and white thing.  I think you would either need a two way lookup table, or maybe if someone wrote a language package for Postgres there is a UDF for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points that are still open with regards to the "best method" and your question.  Although, I believe CASE WHEN will help you:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html

A second solution would be to utilize a group by and simply aggregate the different names/languages against an aggregate function.

Here's the first solution:

For example, within your query, the CASE WHEN can refer to your join condition:

```
select  c1.*,
    COALESCE(c2.name, c1.name) as name,
    CASE 
      WHEN c2.lang_id=2 
        THEN c2.name
      ELSE c1.name
    END as name2

    from cars c1
    left join cars c2 on c1.car_id= c2.car_id and c2.lang_id=2
    CASE 
      WHEN c2.lang_id=2 
        THEN c2.name LIKE '%honda%'
      ELSE c1.name LIKE '%honda%'
    END 
    where c1.lang_id = 1 limit 10;
```

I used CASE WHEN in both the select area as well as the join condition to show that it is not limited to just select columns.

The second solution

```
 select car_id, array_agg(name) as names, array_agg(lang_id order by lang_id) langids
   from cars 
   where name like '%honda%'
   group by car_id
```

Now with your result aggregated, you can choose in each row: which language to show first (it may require a CASE WHEN) or sort may be good enough and there are plenty of other methods.

The second solution should be faster and seems to approximate the end result of more speed, access to the preferred language and search against the name of the vehicle.

I hope this helps!

Comment: second query gives error: ERROR:  column "cars.lang_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: I just updated the query.  You can place the order by directly within the array_agg.  See this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461470/sort-a-text-aggregate-created-with-array-agg-in-postgresql#7510300